# How to add UIBarButtonItem to right side of UIToolBar?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to use

```
[addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton]
```

to put addButton to right side of the bar. What is the correct way?

```
func addBtnToKeyboardTop() {
        let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
        keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
        keyboardToolbar.isTranslucent = false
        keyboardToolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            barButtonSystemItem: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(CreateClubTVC.hideKeyboard)
        )

        addButton.tintColor = UIColor.black

        keyboardToolbar.items = [addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton,addButton]

        membershipFee.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar

    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For that you have to add a flexible space before the button.

**Swift 3**

```
let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()

//creating flexible space
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

// creating button
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(CreateClubTVC.hideKeyboard))

// adding space and button to toolbar
keyboardToolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace,addButton], animated: false)

// adding toolbar to input accessory view
membershipFee.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
```